# Dates in DynamicSQL - cannot agree data types between tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working on one code and I believe I am close but every time I am tweaking it, it's getting worse.

**Problem: There is no error although it shows no result for each loop.**

Purpose of code: Loop through elements of `#PostDate` table and insert them into dynamic SQL in `WHERE` clause and in one of the columns. `#PostDates` are dates converted to `VARCHAR`.

---

The process has 3 steps.

1. Creating a table with dates that will be later used in dynamicSQL:
   (Here is converted dates into varchar since I read that dates cannot be concatenate.

   ```
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PostDate','U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #PostDate

   CREATE TABLE #PostDate(
   Header NVARCHAR(10))

   DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

   WHILE @cnt > - 84
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #PostDate (Header) VALUES
   (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(WK,@cnt,@postdate1),120))
    SET @cnt = @cnt - 1;
   END;
   ```
2. I am creating my table for code below.

   ```
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#finaloutput','U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #finaloutput

   CREATE TABLE #finaloutput(
   BrandCode NVARCHAR(3),
   StayDate DATE)
   ```
3. I am running loop with elements of #PostDate as variables [EDIT] I have decreased the code to simply it as much as I can - still having the same problem.

   ```
   DECLARE @suffix NVARCHAR(10)
   DECLARE #crs INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR

   SELECT Header FROM #PostDate
   FOR READ ONLY
   OPEN #crs
   FETCH NEXT FROM #crs INTO @suffix
   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @str nvarchar(3999)
   SET @str = N';

   INSERT INTO #finaloutput

   select BrandCode,
   StayDate

   FROM #FinalRatEnahnced
   where StayDate < CONVERT(DATETIME,' + @suffix + ', 103) and StayDate >= dateadd(WK,-6,CONVERT(DATETIME,' + @suffix + ', 103))


     EXECUTE sp_executesql @str
     FETCH NEXT FROM #crs INTO @suffix
     END
     CLOSE #crs
     DEALLOCATE #crs
   ```

---

When I tested just the first part of Union with one of the Postdates from #PostDate with the same data types it shows many results:

```
DECLARE @PostDate1 VARCHAR(10) = '20160313'

select BrandCode,
       StayDate,
       CONVERT(DATETIME,@PostDate1, 103) PostDate
from #FinalRatEnahnced
where StayDate < CONVERT(DATETIME,@PostDate1, 103) and StayDate >= dateadd(WK,-6,CONVERT(DATETIME,@PostDate1, 103))
```

**[EDIT] I found the real problem after I simplified the code to only:**

```
select ' + @suffix + ' AS Date
INTO adhoc.ahoc_frcdatatype
'
```

I expected it to be dates of `VARCHAR` type from `#Postdate` and instead is see 4 digits like: 1993, 2000, 1977 `INT`  which are not even the year of the dates from `#Postdate`. So I think when I declare  `@suffix` It truncates the dates.

I would be really happy for any help. Please let me know and I will provide any additional information. Thanks!!

Comment: Im sure you can do that very much easy, show us  sample data and expected output.

Comment: Dear Juan, I've tried to simplify the code as much as I can, therefore it looks like i dont need such a complication. As The final table has 25 columns from those UNION joins and the source has hundreds.

Comment: Can you explain "Here is converted dates into varchar since I read that dates cannot be concatenate."? Whenever you start playing with dates and times using prose you're asking for unpleasant issues, e.g. culture shock, dates sprouting times, un[SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) queries, ... .

Comment: @HABO I declare `@Postdate1` AS `DECLARE @PostDate1 Date = '20161016' ` In dynamic SQL I have `+ @Suffix + ` -> this I refered to as concatenate. So to be able to add the date to the code I `(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@postdate1,120))`.  This way I hoped to have a date in varchar format and input it into the String (dynamic sql). 

Other way I was keeping the dates as date and in this concatenate part I added `''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@suffix,120) + '''` - which also unfortunately didn't work and gave an error as above.

Answer (score 0):

**[Question Solved]**

I did other approach and instead of trying convert dates into varchar and input them into SQL as varchar. 
I used dates and used them like this `''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@suffix,120) + ''' PostDate,`

I've tried it before but I am a stupid sandwich and when I had an error:

> msg Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 3
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

It wasn't about the dates but other column I wrongly defined. `NVARCHAR(5)` instead of `NVARCHAR(3)`.Stupid me.